# Format table heder and body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
  var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
  $(column).hide();
});

$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
  var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
  $(column).toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="margin-left:15px;">Additional information select below:</p>
<p style="display:inline; margin-left:15px">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vendor" />Vendor Details
  <input type="checkbox" name="ONX" />Quantity Level
  <input type="checkbox" name="Cost" />Cost Detail
  <!-- <li><input type="checkbox" name="d"  />d</li> -->

</p>

<table id="testTable" class="fixed_headers">
  <caption>
    <u><h2 >ITEM ONHAND QUANTITIES & GOODS IN TRANSACTION</h2></u>
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr class="header" style="background-color: #3f91bd;color:white; /* position: absolute; width: 83%; */">
      <th class="first">ITEM CODE</th>
      <th class="second">ITEM NAME</th>
      <th class="third">UNIT</th>
      <th class="headcol">ON HAND QTY</th>
      <th class="headcol">GIT</th>
      <th class="headcol">ATP</th>
      <th class="ONX" name="ONX">ONX LOW LMT</th>
      <th class="ONX" name="ONX">ONX HIGH LMT</th>
      <th class="ONX" name="ONX">ONX RE-ORDER-LEVEL</th>
      <th class="Cost">AVG COST</th>
      <th class="Cost">LAST PO PRICE</th>
      <th class="vendor" name="vendor">V_CODE</th>
      <th class="vendor">MAIN_VENDOR</th>
      <th class="vendor">VENDOR_TYPE</th>
      <th class="vendor">Vendor Mx LEAD TIM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="display: block; border: 1px solid green; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll; height:400px; width:850px">
    <tr>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td class="ONX">aaa</td>
      <td class="ONX">aaa</td>
      <td class="ONX">aaa</td>
      <td class="Cost">aaa</td>
      <td class="Cost">aaa</td>
      <td class="vendor">aaa</td>
      <td class="vendor">aaa</td>
      <td class="vendor">aaa</td>
      <td class="vendor">aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td class="ONX">bbb</td>
      <td class="ONX">bbb</td>
      <td class="ONX">bbb</td>
      <td class="Cost">bbb</td>
      <td class="Cost">bbb</td>
      <td>class="vendor">bbb</td>
      <td class="vendor">bbb</td>
      <td class="vendor">bbb</td>
      <td class="vendor">bbb</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The table head and body are not displaying in proper format. I have to fix this issue. Any suggestion for the same will be appreciated. I want to make each `<tbody>` column under corresponding `<thead>` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `display: block;` from the `tbody` inline style

```html
<p style="margin-left:15px;">Additional information select below:</p>
<p style="display:inline; margin-left:15px">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vendor" />Vendor Details
  <input type="checkbox" name="ONX" />Quantity Level
  <input type="checkbox" name="Cost" />Cost Detail
  <!-- <li><input type="checkbox" name="d"  />d</li> -->
</p>

<table id="testTable" class="fixed_headers">
  <caption><u><h2 >ITEM ONHAND QUANTITIES &amp; GOODS IN TRANSACTION</h2></u>
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr class="header" style="background-color: #3f91bd; color: white;">
      <th class="first">ITEM CODE</th>
      <th class="second">ITEM NAME</th>
      <th class="third">UNIT</th>
      <th class="headcol">ON HAND QTY</th>
      <th class="headcol">GIT</th>
      <th class="headcol">ATP</th>
      <th class="ONX" name="ONX">ONX LOW LMT</th>
      <th class="ONX" name="ONX">ONX HIGH LMT</th>
      <th class="ONX" name="ONX">ONX RE-ORDER-LEVEL</th>
      <th class="Cost">AVG COST</th>
      <th class="Cost">LAST PO PRICE</th>
      <th class="vendor" name="vendor">V_CODE</th>
      <th class="vendor">MAIN_VENDOR</th>
      <th class="vendor">VENDOR_TYPE</th>
      <th class="vendor">Vendor Mx LEAD TIM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="border: 1px solid green; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll; height:400px; width:850px">
    <tr>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td class="ONX">aaa</td>
      <td class="ONX">aaa</td>
      <td class="ONX">aaa</td>
      <td class="Cost">aaa</td>
      <td class="Cost">aaa</td>
      <td class="vendor">aaa</td>
      <td class="vendor">aaa</td>
      <td class="vendor">aaa</td>
      <td class="vendor">aaa</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td class="ONX">bbb</td>
      <td class="ONX">bbb</td>
      <td class="ONX">bbb</td>
      <td class="Cost">bbb</td>
      <td class="Cost">bbb</td>
      <td class="vendor">bbb</td>
      <td class="vendor">bbb</td>
      <td class="vendor">bbb</td>
      <td class="vendor">bbb</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```